# Which of these three sentences is correct?

Tags: word-choice

P1/ “What did you ask her?”

P2/

> A) “I asked her whether she was coming.”
> B) “I asked her whether she was coming or not.”
> C) “I asked her if she was coming.”

My question is which one  of these three options is correct? Is the “or not” obligatory? And if all three are correct,which sounds more natural?

Comment: I'm not a native speaker, but I'm sure that all of them are grammatical. But in an informal conversation, the last one is more likely.

Answer (score 1):

All three are correct.

In "B", there is a small redundancy, in that "or not" is already implied by "whether". It is in wide use, however, and not regarded afaik as a grammatical mistake.

Small spelling correction: the word is spelled "whether", though "wether" is a good representation of how it is usually pronounced.